# RtutoR (package containing an R tutorial and ggplot2 tutorial) error: empty apps

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I discovered the package RtutoR just now. It uses functions to deploy an R Tutorial app and a ggplot2 tutorial app using shiny. However, when I use these functions as in documentation in order to launch the shiny apps locally, `launch_tutorial()` and `launch_plotter(list(mtcars=mtcars, iris=iris))`, I get "empty" apps, i.e., without most of the intended features. However, if I go to the [online version](https://nairanup.shinyapps.io/TutorialApp/) of the R Tutorial app, for example, all works fine.

Anyone knows how this may be fixed?

Comment: Do you have all up to date packages and R?

Comment: I have installed ggplot2 and shiny. I believe that is enough, no?

Comment: It would appear `tutoR` has been removed from CRAN. Where would one get this package?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik It is called RtutoR, it is on [CRAN](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/RtutoR/index.html)